# Mysql Enterprise Monitor MEM 3.0 Hardware Requirements

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, shell, monitoring

At work, we are planning to have a dedicated box to run MEM 3.0, we will be monitoring about 30 mysql instances. I wanted to know if anyone has any experience working with MEM 3.0 and what would be an optimal hardware configuration for this project. According to the MEM docs:

```
Recommended System Requirements (if monitoring 100 or more MySQL servers)
4 or more CPU cores
8 or more GB of RAM
Disk I/O subsystem applicable for a write-intensive database (RAID10, RAID 0+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a previous job we monitored 15-20 MySQL instances using MEM before our needs changed and we went with Monyog([Link](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog)). The box it ran on was just a m1.xlarge(4CPU,16gig Mem, 4x420Gig HDs) Amazon EC2 instance([Link to EC2 specs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)) and we never had any issues. Honestly that box was way overkill for only 15-20 instances. I/O is likely to be the bottleneck far before CPU or Memory. If you are worried about I/O issues you might consider an SSD based setup.

In general with HW recommendations for products like this the recommended is usually overkill, especially if you're on real HW, not virtualized stuff.

If you expect your number of instances to grow I'd go with a HW setup that provides ability to support more than you initially have. At 30 instances you're not going to need a heavy metal type setup, but be aware of scaling for the future.